# Amcharts to group Pie chart data by range

Tags: python, django, charts, amcharts4

[image]I have a set of data, marks obtained by students. My aim is to display a pie/bar chart with range category, number of students with marks between 90-100, 80-90, 70-80, 60-70, 50-60, and <50. I am passing Data from python Django to html, which will display the data as a pie chart/ bar chart with those ranges.

One way to do is to populate the data range wise in python using if conditions. etc and then feed the charts which is straight forward.

Since amcharts accept array of hash data, I would populate my data in a hash and append each hash to an array. Say, marks`[{90:10}, {91:5}, {60:6}]` etc.
Right now I populate the data as`[{90-100 : 20},{80-90 : 30}]...`
I want to group those range in amcharts automatically with the given interval.

Is there any way to automatically create range in python/in amcharts using pie/column/bar?
Like I just have to pass the marks and number of students in each mark and then the am chart plugin will automatically group it with the interval we specify?

Edir:
Attached image for reference of chart I am expecting.

The data I will populate in amcharts will be like

```
data = chart.data = [{
  "marks": "95",
  "count": 50
},{
  "marks": "90",
  "count": 165
}, {
  "marks": "91",
  "count": 139
}, {
  "marks": "92",
  "count": 128
}, {
  "marks": "85",
  "count": 99
}, {
  "marks": "81",
  "count": 60}]
```

I want to some mechanism to group the data as

```
data = chart.data = [{
  "marks": "90-100",
  "count": (total of all count between 90 - 100)
},{
  "marks": "80-90",
  "count": (total of all count between 80- 90)
}, {
  "marks": "70-80",
  "count": (total of all count between 70 - 80) 
} , {
  "marks": "<70",
  "count": (total of all count < 70) 
}]
```

Comment: please post your code

Comment: what is the datatype of your data, if it is a pandas data frame you can use [pandas.cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html). The process itself is called `binning` numerical variables to categories.

Comment: since amcharts accept array of hash data, I would populate my data in a hash and append each hash to an array. Say, marks[{90:10}, {91:5}, {60:6}] etc...

Comment: Posted the chart I am expecting also the data format which I have now and what I am expecting

Comment: The chart doesn't perform this grouping automatically. You have to group it yourself. You can either group it in python beforehand like you're currently doing or do it in JS.